# How to read the data in json format?

Tags: json, go

I have a function in which I have to post the data to a url in json format. When I send the data then it will give response in json. But there it will showing me like:-

Output given by code

```
&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 
map[Content-Type:[application/json] X-Request-Id:[CgiFzq669pAYzRABGBAiCQiRtaznvJffAg] 
Keep-Alive:[timeout=60] 
Vary:[Accept-Encoding] 
X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] 
X-Download-Options:[noopen] 
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies:[none] 
Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=631152000] 
X-Frame-Options:[DENY] 
X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block] 
Date:[Tue, 11 Dec 2018 09:35:22 GMT] 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:[Content-Type, Authorization, Accept] 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*] 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:[Link]] 0xc420442080 -1 [] false true map[] 0xc42023e100 0xc4200e0d10}
```

code is :-

```
func Token(c *gin.Context) {
   code := c.Query("code")
   responseToken :=TokenResponse{}
   token := models.PostToken{
     ClientID:     "appllication Id",
     ClientSecret: "applicationSecreteId",
     Code:         "code",
     RedirectUri:  c.Request.Host + c.Request.URL.RequestURI(),
   }
   bindData, err := json.Marshal(token)
   if err != nil {
     panic(err)
   }
   var jsonStr = []byte(string(bindData))
   url :="https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token"
   req, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
   fmt.Println(req, err)
}

type TokenResponse struct {
  Token      string `json:"access_token"`
  Type       string `json:"token_type"`
  ExpiresAt  string `json:"expires_at"`
  MerchantId string `json:"merchant_id"`
}
```

Expected output:-

```
{
  "access_token": "token",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_at": "2019-01-10T08:20:59Z",
  "merchant_id": "id"
}
```

But when I hit "https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token" url in postman then it will give me json but In golang code it will not showing any json it will return the above data. Can anyone  tell me that how i will get the json data from above response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
respBody, Err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)

fmt.Println(string(respBody))

var temp TokenResponse

err := json.Unmarshal(respBody, &temp)
```

Comment: then once you have the respBody, make a struct to decode it and do ``json.Unmarshall(respBody, jstruct)``

Comment: @arcteezy it will not marshal with the given struct see in the code

Comment: You can unmarshal the content into a map from where you can decode it using the key s.

Comment: @Arcteezy Please provide me a small example

Answer (score 3):

You have to read response data like this :

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
response := map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(body,&response)
```

Comment: it will not marshal with the given struct see in the code